# How to control CS signal in SPIDEV moudule on raspberry pi

Tags: c, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, adc

I am trying to use SPIDEV module in Python 2.7 to interface Raspberry Pi 3 with ADS1256 ADC over the SPI bus available on the Raspberry Pi unit.
The project is to communicate with two of those ADCs and sample all the channels (8 channels each) at 250Hz sampling rate.

The functions in the SPIDEV module responsible for data transaction are `xfer` and `xfer2`. The problem with these functions is that they issue a CS active command (bring CS low), do the transaction and issue a CS release command (bring CS high). In order to communicate with ADS1256, a series of commands needs to be sent to the ADC while the CS is kept at logic low. This is possible by listing all the commands together and pass them to the `xfer`/`xfer2` function like this:

```
$xfer2([10, 20, 30, 40])$
```

However, this way of sending commands do not give the ADC sufficient time to process each command or in other words, the timing between instructions violates the timing specifications of the ADC. If, on the other hand, one command is sent at a time, then the CS toggle causes the ADC to forget the previous command.

Two other alternatives suggested online that I tried, introduce too much delay that I cannot squeeze all channel reads within the time frame I have between each sampling instance. These alternatives are:

- WiringPi module: This module has the `wiringPiSPIDataRW` function that is doing the data transaction only and CS can be controlled separately by IO functions in the module. The drawback is that time between each call to this function and as well as the time between bringing the CS low and calling this function is more than 200 microseconds which in aggregate will go over 4 milliseconds (my sampling period) when I sample all the channels.
  Using a separate pin for CS when using SPIDEV: This option also introduced more than 100-microsecond delays between function calls.

These are the two suggestions that I have learned through digging Raspberry Pi community and Stack Overflow.

The `xfer` functions in SPIDEV also provide an argument called delay and according to the documentation it should control the delay between blocks but it only means that how long the CS should be kept low after a transaction is complete. For example: if I issue:

```
$xfer2([12, 23, 34, 46], 1800000, 30)$
```

It will keep CS low for 30 microseconds at the end only after sending 46 is over. It doesn't provide 30 microseconds between each byte i.e 12, 23, 34 and 46 which is an ideal thing that I need. However, if I do

```
xfer2([12])
xfer2([23])
xfer2([34])
xfer2([46])
```

of course, due to nature of Raspberry Pi, the time between each will be more than 100 microsecond which I cannot handle.

So something that will help me control the delay between commands is an ideal thing.

If not possible, something that will let me control CS in the xfer functions so they do not toggle it. Meaning that I can control the CS pin with IO functions. This will prevent a hardware modification on my board which is using the raspberry pi GPIO header CE pin as CS. Although it is still a slow solution but much faster than the functions in the `wiringPi` module.
In a worst case, I will have to modify my hardware and use a different GPIO pin to use as CS.

Thanks for reading